# Read n number of lines from s3 object using AWS lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

In my Lambda I am trying to parse the content of a document from s3 bucket. The document I am processing is a txt file with more than 100Mb. I need to parse only the first line of the file. 
What is the best cost-effective way to read the file?

Currently, I am taking the content using getObjectContent() method and taking the 1st line from it like this.

```
private AmazonS3 s3 =  AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().build ();
GetObjectRequest getObjectRequest = new GetObjectRequest(bucket, key);
S3Object s3Object = s3.getObject(getObjectRequest);


BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s3Object.getObjectContent()));
String firstLine;
try {
  while ((firstLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    logger.log("META PROCESSOR | FIRST LINE OF FILE : " + firstLine);
    break;
  }
} catch (IOException e) {
  logger.log("META PROCESSOR | FAILED TO LOAD FIRST LINE ");
  return null;
}
```

Is it a good way to read the entire content just to read the first line? Is there any method available to read n number of lines from a file or n number of bytes from a file?

Comment: you can use s3 select but s3 select only supports csv and json, however you can try  fetching your document's first line as csv file

Comment: just give it a try and let me know if you need more details

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectSELECTContent.html

Comment: You are doing it correctly. Thanks to your use of BufferedReader, you won't stream the whole contents of the object from S3. Don't forget to close it.